# Loading module on keyboard hotplug

Tags: linux, module

I am trying to learn how to write modules and drivers for Linux systems. Similarly to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120839/usb-kernel-module-does-not-load-on-demand-but-works-fine-with-insmod-and-modprob) question I am trying to run a simple "Hello World" module on USB keyboard hot-plug (code below). Even though initializing the module by commands `insmode` and `modprobe` seem to work (`dmesg` shows debugging messages), the module is not loaded upon plugging in the keyboard.

What I did:

1. Run `make` to produce `hellomodule.ko` file.
2. Copy the `hellomodule.ko` file to /lib/modules/"my_kernel_version"/
3. Run `depmod -a` comand.

After those three steps I have my module added to `modules.alias` and `modules.dep` files. It still does not work.

Is this kernels configuration fault or something entirely different?

System: *Ubuntu 14.04 LTS*; Kernel: *3.14.0*

hellomodule.c:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/usb.h>
#include <linux/usb/input.h>
#include <linux/hid.h>

MODULE_AUTHOR("author");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("helloworld module\n");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static struct usb_device_id hello_id_table [] = {
        { USB_INTERFACE_INFO(USB_INTERFACE_CLASS_HID,
        USB_INTERFACE_SUBCLASS_BOOT,
            USB_INTERFACE_PROTOCOL_KEYBOARD) },
    { } /* Terminating entry */
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE (usb, hello_id_table);

static int hello_probe(struct usb_interface *interface,
    const struct usb_device_id *id)
{
    pr_debug("HelloModule: USB keyboard probe function called\n");
    return 0;
}

static void hello_disconnect(struct usb_interface *interface)
{
    pr_debug("HelloModule: USB keyboard disconnect function called\n");
}

static struct usb_driver hello_driver = {
//.owner =  THIS_MODULE,
.name =     "hello_driver",
.probe =    hello_probe,
.disconnect =   hello_disconnect,
.id_table = hello_id_table
};

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
   int retval = 0;

   pr_debug("HelloModule: Hello World!\n");
   retval = usb_register(&hello_driver);
   if (retval)
       pr_debug("HelloModule: usb_register failed. Error number %d", retval);

   return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
    usb_deregister(&hello_driver);
    pr_debug("HelloModule: exit\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Makefile:

```
obj-m := hellomodule.o
CFLAGS_hellomodule.o := -DDEBUG

KDIR  :=  /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build

default:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @bacchus Not really. I have switched to another computer with the same system installed on it and without changing anything in the module itself - and it worked. I suspect I had some problems with my kernel configuration, although I did not investigate the issue further.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem. In my case it was caused by the `usbhid` module being already loaded, since I was using a USB mouse.

If I understand it correctly, in Ubuntu 14.04, the udev rule that loads the proper module(s) when a new device is attached is the following (located in `/lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules`):

```
DRIVER!="?*", ENV{MODALIAS}=="?*", RUN{builtin}="kmod load $env{MODALIAS}"
```

As you can see, `kmod load` is executed only if the new device has no driver. However, if `usbhid` is already loaded, the just-attached keyboard already has a driver. Therefore the "hello world" module is not loaded.

A possible solution is to modify/override the udev rule by removing the `DRIVER!="?*"` condition, thus turning it into:

```
ENV{MODALIAS}=="?*", RUN{builtin}="kmod load $env{MODALIAS}"`.
```

Another possible workaround is to unload the `usbhid` module before attaching the keyboard. Of course, that will cause all USB keyboards, mice and other HID class devices to stop working until you attach the new keyboard.