# How to install simple usb hotplug driver?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, usb, kernel-module

It is my understanding that a `struct usb_driver` can be bound to a kernel module using `module_usb_driver()`, which allows `.probe()` to decide whether or not to handle a device as it is connected.

I seem to be mistaken, as the following module does not seem to be getting `probe()`ed when I plug in my usb keyboard.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/usb.h>

#define USB_VENDOR_ID 0x045e  /* Microsoft */
#define USB_PRODUCT_ID 0x0750 /* Wired Keyboard 600 (model 1366) */

static int init_my_module(struct usb_interface *intf, const struct usb_device_id *id)
{
    pr_debug("Hello USB probe!\n");
    return -ENODEV; /* Don't actually handle the device */
}

static void cleanup_my_module(struct usb_interface *intf)
{
    pr_debug("Goodbye USB!\n");
}

static const struct usb_device_id device_table[] = {
    { USB_DEVICE(USB_VENDOR_ID, USB_PRODUCT_ID) },
    { }                 /* Terminating entry */
};

static struct usb_driver hello_driver = {
    .name =     "Hello USB",
    .probe =    init_my_module,
    .disconnect =   cleanup_my_module,
    .id_table = device_table
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(usb, device_table);
module_usb_driver(hello_driver);
```

I am trying to install it by compiling with `make`, then `insmod`ing it.  Then I plug in my MS600 keyboard (and unplug it, repeatedly), but my `probe` never is called.

```
will@Desk ~/code/eudypt/eudyptula5 $ dmesg | grep Hello
[44553.388256] usbcore: registered new interface driver Hello USB
```

then I `rmmod` it, and it is removed successfully:

```
will@Desk ~/code/eudypt/eudyptula5 $ dmesg | grep Hello
[44553.388256] usbcore: registered new interface driver Hello USB
[45010.513570] usbcore: deregistering interface driver Hello USB
```

So my module seems to be registering with `usbcore`, but it is not being probed by it.  Am I misunderstanding how `probe()` works?  Do I have to recompile a new kernel with this module included?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307579/loading-module-on-keyboard-hotplug

Comment: I took a look at that answer, my `/lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules` does not have the part he mentions removing.  OP there just tried it on a VM, which apparently worked, but I'm specifically wondering if I'm using `probe` incorrectly or if `insmod` is insufficient for this type of module.